# Summation as exponent

Tags: math-mode, formatting, superscripts

```
 x^{\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n {n \choose k}p^k + 1}
```

[image]

How can I make the exponent look smaller?

Comment: `\displaystyle` is causing the exponent to be over-large.  if the reason you're using that is to get the limits above and below the sum, then use `\sum\limits` instead.  but gonzalo's answer is better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead fo trying to accommodate such a big expression as a superscript, I'd suggest you to use a name for it and then explain this name:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
x^{\alpha},\quad\text{where } \alpha=\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} p^k + 1.
\]

$x^{\alpha},\text{ where } \alpha=\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} p^k + 1$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Also, `\choose` is an old command; use `\binom{}{}` instead.

Answer (score 3):

I would probably remove the `\displaystyle` and enclose it in parentheses, like this:

[image]

and then shrink it down even further using `\scriptscriptstyle`, like this:

[image]

which I find plenty readable... although Gonzalo's suggestion of giving it an intermediate name is probably the clearest, unless you're all out of variable names to spare. :)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

$x^{(\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} p^k + 1)}$

$x^{(\raisebox{.35pt}{$\scriptscriptstyle{\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} p^k + 1}$})}$

\end{document}
```